# Source Control R scripts in Visual Studio Git

Tags: r, git, visual-studio, tfs, rstudio

I have a TFS server enabled for Git. I work half the time in Visual Studio and half the time in RStudio. I would like to be able to configure RStudio to talk to the TFS git server so that I can source control R scripts directly from RStudio. Is there a way to achieve this? If not, what is the best workflow here: Write scripts in RStudio and copy them over into a VS project!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've enabled git support in RStudio by following the [documented steps](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN).

If so, then you should be able to clone your repository from TFS, make your changes, commit them locally and then push those changes to the TFS remote whenever you are ready.

Don't forget that git support in TFS is just plain old git. You can use the standard git command line utilities and/or 3rd party git clients as well as Visual Studio.